# How to remove rivets?

Tags: tools, screws, hand-tools

I have to remove these rivets (see pics).

What tool can I use for that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What material are they set into?

Comment: They are set into wooden boards

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are [rivets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivet) (specifically pop-rivets), they are a permanent fastener not intended to be easily or routinely disassembled and reassembled.

[image]

There are many ways to remove them

### Drill

You can drill them out with a HSS drill bit of appropriate diameter for the stem of the rivet. Once you have drilled out the centre, the heads will fall out.

### Punch

You may be able to punch out the center using a hammer and a suitably sized punch.

### Grind

You can grind off the head using an angle grinder or something similar. Once the head is removed, the remainder will fall out or can easily be pushed out.

### Chisel

Some people say they chop off the heads using a chisel and hammer. I guess they mean a [cold-chisel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chisel#Cold_chisel) of the type intended for use on metal, not the type of chisel intended to be used on wood.

Comment: Actually, since pop rivets are frequently aluminum, and because you need a fairly thin edge to get under the head, a wood chisel is more effective than a cold chisel. This does put more wear and tear on the cutting edge of the chisel, so you won't want to use your best, and you will need to resharpen it more than if used strictly on wood. Your choice of chisel, grinder or drill mostly will depend on access  to the rivet.

Comment: Grinding would probably be a last resort in this particular instance since they're set in wood. Too much chance of causing damage to the wood with a slightly errant application of the grinding disk.

Comment: I'd grind it just enough to make the top flat, so I can dimple it on-center with a center punch... so the drill seeks center instead of hunting all over a rough surface.

Answer (score 6):

I always drill. Works like a charm, rivet's metal is quite soft.
On the third picture, rivet et gone already, you should be able to push it out.