# How to use rivnut?

Tags: metal

I came across this funny things called [rivnut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivet_nut).

In what case would you use these ?

I can think of a few ideas but maybe there are typical usage.

For those new to this, see this [Youtube video showing how it works](https://youtu.be/P_uu_ba6qAM?t=1m36s).

[image: Rivnuts]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a promotion of a product rather than a request for expert advice. Even if it is not promotional, it is too broad and opinion based.

Comment: why close it, the question has been answered.

Comment: what the hell... closing for the sake of closing. Thanks for such unproductive attitude

Comment: related: Plusnut vs Rivnut http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/109458/rivnut-vs-plusnut-when-to-favor-which-one

Answer (score 1):

You can use them in place of rivets. Properly installed, you can unbolt the pieces of metal that are joined by rivnuts if you ever need to. With rivets, although you can separate the pieces of metal joined by rivets, it is more labor intensive (e.g., drilling out rivets).

They are frequently used in automotive work. For example, I used them to install aftermarket fenders to the body of my Jeep Wrangler. I also used them when I was an automotive tech to install accessories on vehicles.

Comment: Yes, it seems great to have modularity "built-in" (being able to screw in-and-out connecting pieces) versus rivets where you have to "destroy" the whole thing, c.f. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/94709/how-to-remove-rivets

Comment: By "install aftermarket fenders to the body of my Jeep Wrangler", do you mean something like that? http://precisioncarrestoration.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/DSC03817.jpg

Comment: @AdrienBe-https://www.northridge4x4.com/fits/2014-jeep-wrangler-jk-sport-3-6l-6mt-4wd-95-4wb-2dr/fenders/17-02-030-poison-spyder-crusher-flares-standard-width-front?gclid=CjwKEAiA3NTFBRDKheuO6IG43VQSJAA74F779-BFIxkGG2ZZ-AXedp_X-kPjkTdDCxu9_o-f-5dzrxoCkJXw_wcB

Comment: Related to the vehicle customization topic: it's also awesome to use it for van conversion. i.e. to make your furniture modular (being able to screw it in & out as needed). An example here, although done with Plusnuts, it can be done with Rivnuts http://faroutride.com/plusnut

Answer (score 1):

The ones with the small washer on the one end are used with a certain type of pipe hanger  called a "clevis hanger".

Comment: You mean this I suppose https://goo.gl/vbhofj . Do you mean that you put the rivnut in the clevis hanger to then be able to screw it to anything else ?

Comment: yes, just as some of the pictures show. After you hang the pipe you can level the pipe by turning the nut in or out on the threaded rod. (have used thousands)